# How to grep a specific line and their subsequnet line with a specific pattern?

Tags: ubuntu, parsing, grep

I have a data in the following format.

```
>ab:xy_a0by98-2 \Movie= top gun \actor= Tom \Genere=Action \Length=234 \Credits=30 \pe=1 \summry=(Tom|action|234)
Top Gun is a 1986 American action drama film directed by Tony Scott, and produced by Don Simpson and Jerry Bruckheimer

>ab:xy_b0ha81-5 \Movie= Thor \actor= chris hemsworth \Genere=Action \Length=321 \Credits=20 \pe=0 \summry=(chris|Action|321)
Thor embarks on a journey unlike anything he's ever faced a quest for inner peace

>ab:xy_c0ma65-1 \Movie= Batman \actor= Bale \Genere=Action \Length=251 \Credits=30 \pe=1 \summry=(Bale|Action|251)
From American Psycho to Batman Begins to Vice, Christian Bale is a bonafide A-list star
But he missed out on plenty of huge roles along the way.

>ab:xy_d0fc78-2 \Movie= Joker \actor= Phoenix \Genere=thriller \Length=341 \Credits=35 \pe=2 \summry=(phoenix|thriller|341)
Joker is a 2019 American psychological thriller film directed and produced by Todd Phillips
who co-wrote the screenplay with Scott Silver

>ab:xy_e0ra81-2 \Movie= Superman \actor= henry cavill \Genere=Action \Length=254 \Credits=28 \pe=1 \summry=(cavill|action|254)
Henry William Dalgliesh Cavill is a British actor
He is known for his portrayal of Charles Brandon in Showtime's The Tudors
```

I want to extract all the entries with their description (data between two `>`) which contain pe=1, each entiry starts with the `>` symobol as follows:

```
>ab:xy_a0by98-2 \Movie= top gun \actor= Tom \Genere=Action \Length=234 \Credits=30 \pe=1 \summry=(Tom|action|234)
Top Gun is a 1986 American action drama film directed by Tony Scott, and produced by Don Simpson and Jerry Bruckheimer

>ab:xy_c0ma65-1 \Movie= Batman \actor= Bale \Genere=Action \Length=251 \Credits=30 \pe=1 \summry=(Bale|Action|251)
From American Psycho to Batman Begins to Vice, Christian Bale is a bonafide A-list star
But he missed out on plenty of huge roles along the way.

>ab:xy_e0ra81-2 \Movie= Superman \actor= henry cavill \Genere=Action \Length=254 \Credits=28 \pe=1 \summry=(cavill|action|254)
Henry William Dalgliesh Cavill is a British actor
He is known for his portrayal of Charles Brandon in Showtime's The Tudors
```

I tried `grep 'pe=1' input.txt`. But it extracts only the first line of each record. I require subsequent lines of the entry till next `>` symbol

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. Do you bother about empty lines in between coming? Please confirm once.

Comment: added the code I tried. I am a newbie in the field. Apologizes for the mistakes

Comment: The empty lines are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. If you are ok not to have empty lines then this will help here. Simple explanation would be, setting RS to paragraph mode and in main program checking if line starts from `>` and also contains pe=1 then print that line.

Also since OP confirmed there are control M characters in Input_file, so firstly remove them by doing:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > tmp && mv tmp Input_file
```

Then run following code to get actual output:

```
awk -v RS= '/^>.*\\pe=1/' Input_file
```

Comment: I tried the code but it returns entire data. the filter `pe=1` was not functioning

Comment: @batman, previous one was tested. I edited it to have \ also in regex. Please do try my edited one and let me know how it goes. cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately a line containig `pe=2` was also extracted by the code... which I don't require

Comment: @batman, ohh not sure why its not working for you; at least I ran code and it worked fine. Try checking if your file has control M characters in it? Run a command like: `cat -v Input_file` and let me know if you see any control M chars there?

Comment: Ya. there are M characetrs in the file when I checked `cat -v Input_file`

Comment: @batman, oh ok, let me edit my code to deal with them also.

Comment: @batman, Please run my edited code once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I get the same output as input even after running this code...

Comment: @batman, ok, 1 more thing do you have multiple entries of pe in same line?

Comment: no multiple entries only once per record..

Comment: I tried this code with the same example given in this question. But it extracts `pe=2` also

Comment: @batman, ok do 1 thing, first remove your Control M characters by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > tmp && mv tmp Input_file` and then run my posted command in my answer.

Comment: @batman, Your welcome. Also I hope you don't need Control M characters in your file? Just confirming.

Comment: Not required... Thanks for confirming